# Firebase deployment Error : In console it is showing that deployment is successful, But the api is not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

The Error I am getting is this:
[image]

[image]
I have tried deleting node modules and package-lock.json.
it did not work.
The firebase emulators are working fine , but every time I try to deploy the function, it is giving the same error.